# How to sort a object in ascending order by the value of a key in js?

Tags: javascript, sorting

How can sort the values 1,99,1,50 in javascript?

Here is input: `var map = {test:1, test2:99, test3:1, test4: 50}`

here is the targeted output: `{test2:99, test4:50, test3:1, test:1}`

Here is what I have tried:

```
function sortMap(map) {
    var temp = [];
    for(let prop in map) {
        if(map.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
            temp.push({name:prop, size:map[prop]});
        }
    }
    return temp.sort(function(b, a) {
        return a.size - b.size
    });
}
```

Comment: [It's working](https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/sepxeaup/)

Comment: I guess it should be b-a

Comment: Your input is the same as your output. And your `sortMap` function returns an array not an object, which however seems to be much more suited to your task.

Comment: Objects have no "order" per se.

Comment: You could make it neater using `Object.keys` and just chaining `map` and `sort` but yea it appears to be working? https://jsfiddle.net/mLmupfLb/

Comment: Sorry folks. Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1069666/sorting-javascript-object-by-property-value

Answer (score 0):

You cannot actually sort an object's keys, but you can sort the keys and get the values accordingly.

```js
var map = { test: 1, test2: 99, test3: 1, test4: 50 },
    keys = Object.keys(map).sort(function (a, b) { return map[b] - map[a]; });

keys.forEach(function (k) {
    document.write(k + ': ' + map[k] + '<br>');
});
```